# json4s JDouble(NaN) writes to a string "NaN"

Tags: scala, json4s

I am having an issue with json4s where it is picking up the JDouble(NaN) and when I do a write to json,

```
 Serialization.write(json)
```

I am getting the output as a string in JSON "NaN" and it is causing conflicts when I am adding to records in my elastic search instance because its trying to figure out Double and String.

Is there a way to just replace it with a compatible type during the write?

I am not sure how to handle it in a custom serializer like so:

```
class NoneJNullSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Option[_]](format => ( {
  case JDouble(NaN) => JNull
}))
```

The NaN is not allowed in JDouble.

I've also tried in the JSON String to do something like

```
.replaceAll("NaN", null)
```

but than I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: `case JDouble(x) if JDouble.isNaN(x) => ...` perhaps?

Comment: There is no function isNaN on JDouble.

Comment: I guess, I don't know what's `JDouble` then ... I was assuming it was an alias for java.lang.Double.

Comment: Part of json4s's variables, this might work: case JDouble(x) if JDouble(x.isNaN) => JNull

Comment: `case JDouble(x) if (java.lang.Double.isNaN(x)) => ...` then?